# Simulating Git in Bash for academic purposes

Tags: bash, git

The idea is to have a *minimal* script that demonstrate how Git works. I would like to be able to build objects, trees, blobs, commits and demonstrate that a Git repository could be created using bash commands, zlib algorithm and SHA1.

I am not an expert in bash and I would like some review:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
# Description: This script is used to emulate the git command
GIT_DIR=.git
GIT_NAME="John Doe"
GIT_EMAIL="john.doe@acme.inc"
GIT_AUTHOR_DATE="2020-10-01 12:00:00 +0100"
GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="2020-10-01 12:00:00 +0100"

PROGRAM=$(basename "$0")

LAST_OBJECT=""
LAST_TREE=""

# Return the Git mode of a file
mode () {
    if [[ -d $1 ]]; then
        echo 40000
    else
        echo "100$(stat -c '%a' "$1")"
    fi
}

# Get the Git hash of a file
hash () {
    sha1sum "$1" | cut -d ' ' -f 1
}

inflate () {
    #python3 -c "import zlib,sys;sys.stdout.buffer.write(zlib.compress(sys.stdin.read().encode()))" < $1
    zlib-flate -uncompress < "$1"
}

deflate () {
    #python3 -c "import zlib,sys;sys.stdout.buffer.write(zlib.compress(sys.stdin.read().encode()))" < $1
    zlib-flate -compress < "$1"
}

# Create object file
object () {
    tmpfile=$(mktemp).zlib
    deflate "$1" > "$tmpfile"
    HASH=$(hash "$1")
    echo "Created object $HASH"
    PREFIX=$(echo "$HASH" | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | cut -c1-2)
    mkdir -p ".git/objects/$PREFIX"
    mv "$tmpfile" ".git/objects/$PREFIX/$(echo "$HASH" | cut -d ' ' -f 1 | cut -c3-)"
    LAST_OBJECT=$HASH
}

# Initialize a Git repository
init () {
    mkdir -p $GIT_DIR/objects $GIT_DIR/refs $GIT_DIR/refs/heads $GIT_DIR/refs/tags $GIT_DIR/branches
    echo "Initialized empty Git repository in $(pwd)/$GIT_DIR/"
}

# Create blob object
blob () {
    blobfile=$(mktemp).blob
    echo -ne "blob $(wc -c < "$1")\0" > "$blobfile"
    cat "$1" >> "$blobfile"
    echo "Created blob $blobfile for $1"
    object "$blobfile"
    rm "$blobfile"
}

# Create tree object
tree () {
    treefile=$(mktemp).tree
    files=$(find "$1" -maxdepth 1 -type f | sort -k 10)
    for file in $files; do
        blob "$file"
        echo -ne "$(mode "$file") $(basename "$file")\0$(echo "$LAST_OBJECT" | sed -e 's/../\\x&/g')" >> "$treefile"
    done
    headertreefile=$(mktemp).tree
    echo -ne "tree $(wc -c < "$treefile")\0" > "$headertreefile"
    cat "$treefile" >> "$headertreefile"
    object "$headertreefile"
    LAST_TREE=$LAST_OBJECT
    rm "$treefile" "$headertreefile"
}

# Create commit object
commit () {
    commitfile=$(mktemp).commit
    tree "$1"
    echo "tree $LAST_OBJECT" > "$commitfile"
    if [ -s $GIT_DIR/refs/heads/master ]; then
        echo "parent $(cat "$GIT_DIR/refs/heads/master")" >> "$commitfile"
    fi
    author_date=$(date --date="$GIT_AUTHOR_DATE" +%s)
    committer_date=$(date --date="$GIT_COMMITTER_DATE" +%s)
    echo "author $GIT_NAME <$GIT_EMAIL> $author_date +0100" >> "$commitfile"
    echo "committer $GIT_NAME <$GIT_EMAIL> $committer_date +0100" >> "$commitfile"
    echo "" >> "$commitfile"
    echo "$2" >> "$commitfile"
    echo -ne "commit $(wc -c < "$commitfile")\0$(cat "$commitfile")\n" > "$commitfile"
    object "$commitfile"
    rm "$commitfile"
    echo "$LAST_OBJECT" > "$GIT_DIR/refs/heads/master"
    echo "ref: refs/heads/master" > "$GIT_DIR/HEAD"
    echo "Created commit $LAST_OBJECT"
    echo "Head is now at $LAST_TREE"
}

help() {
    echo "Usage: $PROGRAM <command> [options]\n"
    echo "Commands:"
    echo "    init                  Initialize Git Repository"
    echo "    tree PATH             Create a tree object"
    echo "    blob PATH             Create a blob object"
    echo "    commit PATH MESSAGE   Create a commit object"
    echo ""
    echo "For help with each command run:"
    echo "$PROGRAM <command> -h|--help"
    echo ""
}

command=$1
case $command in
    "" | "-h" | "--help")
        help
        ;;
    *)
        shift
        ${command} $@
        if [ $? = 127 ]; then
            echo "Error: '$command' is not a known command." >&2
            echo "       Run '$PROGRAM --help' for a list of known commands." >&2
            exit 1
        fi
        ;;
esac
```

One use could be:

```
mkdir repo && cd repo
echo "Hello World" > hello.txt
echo "README" > README.md
./mingit.sh init 
./mingit.sh commit . "Initial commit"
./mingit.sh commit . "Second commit"
...
```

Then one could use git to show `git log` or `git diff`.

I am missing the `index` file which looks complicated.

Comment: I strongly recommend you check your script at shellcheck.net

Comment: If this is to learn a little bit about how git is built internally, then fine, I guess. If this is meant to teach a user how to use git then I consider it less educational than using the real thing.